# How to render HTML tags with conditional in Smarty template engine?

Tags: php, angularjs, smarty

I'm having a select tag with three options. Each of them i want to use `{if}{/if}` to check the conditionals to display or not, but it's cause a problem when it render the first option with content

`<option value="? string:detail ?" selected></option>`

Here is my code:

```
<select ng-model="report_type" name="report_type">
   {if (isReportView)}<option value="detail">Detail view</option>{/if}
   {if (isReportView)}<option value="summary">Summary view</option>{/if}
   {if (isSalaryView)}<option value="salary">Salary view</option>{/if}
</select>
```

With `isReportView` is `false`, the first and second did not displayed is right, but it's also rendered another option tag as i mention above. So how to prevent it render that option?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you use "ng-show" To show or hide.
For example in your code:

```
<select ng-model="report_type" name="report_type">
   <option ng-show="isReportView" value="detail">Detail view</option>
   <option ng-show="isReportView" value="summary">Summary view</option>
   <option ng-show="isSalaryView" value="salary">Salary view</option>
</select>
```